# How to change coordinate system on Pixmap

Tags: qt, drawing, geometry, qimage, qpixmap

Who knows how to move from top left coordinate system to the default, where X/Y-axis starts from the left bottom corner (like we always draw them) on QPixmap/Qimage

Comment: Did you already read the QPainter's documentation about [coordinate transforms](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#coordinate-transformations)?

Comment: @Roku yes, but I don't understand how can I do what I told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
QMatrix m;
m.translate(0,size.height());
m.scale(1,-1);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&pic);
painter.setMatrix(m);
```